# Flux stores - managing store dependencies... waitFor vs addChangeListener vs raise action

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

This is a question about a sensible approach for managing inter-store dependencies.  I have an app which provides various dashboards for parts of a system.  Each part of the system has a dedicated controller-view and store.

I'm now working on an overall dashboard which will represent a top-level summary of the dashboard data exposed by each existing store.  Given that there's a fair amount of transformation in each store, I want to have my new `SummaryStore` depend upon each of the existing stores and pull data from each.  Nice and DRY.

The system has a very high throughput of data.  Each dedicated store, when it receives an action from the dispatcher, will determine whether the action mutates the state for that particular store (it often doesn't) and only call `emitChange()` if it does.  This minimises the amount of re-rendering the UI does.

I want to preserve that "only emit change if you have to" approach with the summary store.  How to sensibly achieve this?

At present I have a number of alternatives:

1. Expose a property on called `hasChanged` on each of my existing stores which is true when that store's state has been mutated and false otherwise.  Use `waitFor` in my `SummaryStore`, listening to the same events as the dedicated store and only triggering `emitChange()` if `hasChanged` on a dedicated store is `true`

This approach seems fairly reasonable and pragmatic. The downside as I see it is having this store effectively know what actions each of the other stores will respond to and re-implementing that in the `SummaryStore` so we are granular in our `waitFor`s.  That's not so bad though.  I also note that this exact same approach appears to have been used in the official FluxUtils `FluxStore`:  http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html#api

2. Have the `SummaryStore` listen to the `emitChange()` of each dedicated store and only change state / `emitChange()` in the `SummaryStore` in those callbacks.  You could potentially even bin the Dispatcher registration too.  Controversial!

This has the potential to make things rather non-deterministic since the mutation would take place when the `emitChange()` came from the dedicated store.  Sure, you could still use `waitFor` (if you kept the Dispatcher registration) but I'm unclear as to whether that would give you back the determinism you desire and it might make for an unclear architecture. I've done some digging and seen no evidence of anyone else having stores listen to stores.  That rather sets alarm bells off for me - but perhaps that's irrational.

3. Have each store raise an action in the event of a state change.  The `SummaryStore` would not subscribe to the same messages as the dedicated stores but only to the actions raised by the dedicated stores.

This uses the dispatcher mechanism quite nicely and (unless I'm missing something) removes the need for duplicating the message subscription code of each of the dedicated stores in the `SummaryStore`.  No need for `waitFor` all that jazz, just have it respond to the actions dispatched by each store.  The only thing that gives me pause for thought is

---

The question is, which of these is most "the Flux way"?

Comment: You could either combine the stores (reflux allows this) which would require a top level component subscribe to the combined store and pass the data as props or send the data received action to both the summary store and the dedicated store.

Comment: By the way, you would get more visibility if you tagged your question reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that option 3 breaks the flux-pattern. Having stores raise their own actions seems like a dangerous path, with potential circular references and loops. Best to let only views or server side raise actions.
You state that you want to that minimize emit-events in order to:

> This minimises the amount of re-rendering the UI does

In a typical flux-react setup, the stores quite crudely emit changes (even if in fact the received action did NOT result in any change). The views responding to the change get new state from store and determine whether or not a UI update should takes place. Either through react's virtual DOM diff engine, or hand-rolled through a shouldComponentUpdate function.

My 2 cents: I would say option 1 is the most flux way. I regularly apply a dashboard-like store in such a setup to pre-process data for the views, but also to prevent any circular waitFor cycles between stores.